# Search optimization in the array of Shapely polygons

Tags: python, search, optimization, shapely

I have some Python code with can visualize triangular mesh. The aim is to change the color of clicked triangle. My realization is too straight-forward and very long in execution time. I wonder if it is possible to optimize my algorithm with some data structures for example binary heap or if there was a more elegant and faster method.
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mesh import Mesh
from matplotlib.pylab import figure, gca, triplot, show, cla
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

def refreshPlot():
    cla()
    ax.tripcolor(mesh.nodes[:,0], mesh.nodes[:,1], mesh.elements, facecolors=zfaces, edgecolors='r')
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.set_title('Click to select')
    show()

def onClick(event):
    (x,y)   = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
    clicked_point = Point((x,y))
    for i in range(mesh.n_elements):   
        if(triangles[i].contains(clicked_point)==True):
            zfaces[i] = 0
            refreshPlot()

mesh = Mesh('relais.msh', False, 1e-03)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
zfaces = np.ones(mesh.n_elements)
triangles = [Polygon(mesh.nodes[tri]) for tri in mesh.elements]
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
refreshPlot()
```